# Trouble finding central directory when reading ZIP file

Tags: zip

I've been trying to develop my own zip library by reading the Wikipedia article on it, for the sake of learning something new.
My first file is a zipped text file containing 215 bytes. It works really well, and the 
End of central directory (EOCD) correctly gives me the offset of the central directory header.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2DLs.png

However, when trying larger files, like in this example a zipped 216 byte text file I can't
seem to find the offset anymore. From the info I've found in the Wikipedia article and from Google, the offset to the central director should be 16 bytes after the EOCD, but the value
at that position doesn't correctly show the offset I'm looking for.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/emztj.png

It feels like im missing something about how the data should be interpreted since applications like 7-zip and Windows Explorer can read it fine. What am I missing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does one find the start of the "Central Directory" in zip files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802097/how-does-one-find-the-start-of-the-central-directory-in-zip-files)

Answer (score 0):

I posted my own answer to this question which contains a link to a working solution that you could use to learn about this problem.

Link: [How does one find the start of the central directory in zip files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802097/how-does-one-find-the-start-of-the-central-directory-in-zip-files/27805375#27805375)